# ** (CompileError) test/integration/listing_authors.test.exs:9: BookcaseApi.Author.__struct__/1

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a integration test I am working on, but right now it won't compile.

**listing_authors.test.exs**

```
defmodule ListingAuthorsIntegrationTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: true
  use Plug.Test
  alias BookcaseApi.Web.Router
  alias BookcaseApi.Author

  @opts Router.init([])
  test 'listing authors' do
    author = %Author{name: "Oscar Wilde"}
             |> Repo.insert!

    # Note: single quotes are for char lists.
    # Note: double quotes are for strings.
    conn = conn(:get, "/authors")
    response = Router.call(conn, @opts)

    assert response.status == 200
    assert response.resp_body == author
  end
end
```

**author.ex**

```
defmodule BookcaseApi.Author do
  use BookcaseApi.Web, :model

  schema "name" do

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [])
    |> validate_required([])
  end
end
```

**stacktrace.txt**

```
λ mix test test/integration/listing_authors.test.exs                             0 < 18:39:12
** (CompileError) test/integration/listing_authors.test.exs:9: BookcaseApi.Author.__struct__/1 is undefined, cannot expand struct BookcaseApi.Author
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
    test/integration/listing_authors.test.exs:8: (module)
(stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
```

Any help on how I can get the integration test to compile would be awesome.

**Update June 4, 2017**
This is a phoenix v1.3 rc2 project that was generated with the below command,

```
mix phx.new bookcase_api --no-html --no-brunch
```

I then generated a model for the project with the below command,

```
mix phoenix.gen.json Author name
```

Comment: That's strange.. does this work in `iex -S mix`: `%BookcaseApi.Author{name: "Oscar Wilde"}`? If yes, can you try doing `mix clean && mix compile` once and then run the test?

Comment: @Dogbert thanks for the comment, however `iex -S mix`: `%BookcaseApi.Author{name: "Oscar Wilde"}` does not work, and displays the same error message as stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dennis already pointed out that you've used two different generators for the app and the model, so that could definitely be the source of your problem. There's another issue with the model that was generated, too. It looks like you intended to generate an `Author` schema with a single `name` field, but it looks like you didn't pass it a name for the database table so it interpreted `name` as the table name. With the new generators, you also need to give it a context -- in this case you might want to use Authors, in case you want to add more modules related to your Authors api. So your generator command would be:

`mix phx.gen.json Authors Author authors name:string`

(:string can technically be left off, the generator assumes you want fields to be :string time unless told otherwise)

The correct generated structure would look like:

```
defmodule BookcaseApi.Authors.Author do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "authors" do
    field :name, :string
    timestamps
  end
end
```

The Phoenix website's documentation hasn't been updated yet to cover the new generators, but the source files are well documented. Here are the docs for the new json generator (also accessible with `mix help phx.gen.json`): https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/lib/mix/tasks/phx.gen.json.ex

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your problem was in using `mix phoenix.gen.json` (which is the Phoenix 1.2 generator) with a Phoenix 1.3 project. Try using `mix phx.gen.json` instead. Your model is trying to `use BookcaseApi.Web, :model` whereas Phoenix 1.3 schemes should `use Ecto.Schema` instead.